# Changing GEdit's default file open/save path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, gedit

When opening/saving a file using GEdit you see a open/save file dialog. The default location to open/save files in is `~`. Is there anyway I can change it so that the default open/save is `~/Desktop/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas you might be interested in Scribes - http://mystilleef.blogspot.com/

Evidently in gnome ctrl-shift-o will let you open a new file on the desktop.  I haven't verified since I'm testing out gnome-shell and not running gnome right now.

Hope this helps,
-pbr

Answer (score 3):

Similar things have [been requested](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/194904), although it seems they don't plan on changing it. It is hardcoded into gedit that the initial default save directory is the user's home folder. After you save to a different location, gedit will remember the new location and make that the default for the next save. With that said, just open gedit and save something to the desktop. The next time you go to save something it should point there already, although if you save somewhere else it will change. There is no way of changing the default to **always** be a specific location unless you edit the source.

Answer (score 0):

With a bash script yes...

`cd ~/Desktop/ gedit -s`

you create a launcher, associating the script and gedit will open and save always on desktop